# How to separate css style from common to different statement

Tags: css

I have two elements, I want to apply same background style, but different font style to them, how to write the style statement in the header part without having to write duplicate statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't get simpler than:

```
#element1, #element2 {
    background: red
}
#element1 {
    font: 20px sans-serif
}
#element2 {
    font: 24px serif
}
```

You should read up on [selector grouping](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorgrouping).

Comment: +1 for grouping... probably a better solution than common classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply more than one class to an element...

HTML:

```
<div class="common div1">My Stuff</div>
<div class="common div2">My Stuff 2</div>
```

CSS:

```
.common {
background-color:blue;
background-image:url("bill.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.div1 {
font-family:Calibri;
}
.div2 {
font-family:Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a class + an ID

```
<style type="text/css">
div.common { background:blabla; }
div #type1 { font-style:blabla; }
div #type2 { font-style:otherblabla; }
</style>
<div class="common" id="type1">asd</div>
<div class="common" id="type2">asd</div>
```

Or use the method posted by the other guy, 2 classes